# Get data from a join table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pull data from my database which ahs the following:

x3 tables:

```
docs
  doc_id - index
cat
  cat_id - index
doc_cat_join
  doc_id - foreign key to docs/doc_id
  cat_id - foreign key to cats/cat_id
```

I have inserted some data so that I have a row in cats and a rows in docs and in the join table bound a cat_id with a doc_id which all works fine. I am tying to pull that from the tables and show it, here is my approach so far but not getting anything out and am wondering where my failings are as I am getting no errors?

when I visit the cateroy page in my scripts I GET the id from the url:

```
    $id = $_GET['cat_id'];           

    $q = sprintf("
        SELECT
        docs.doc_id,doc_name
        FROM docs
        INNER JOIN doc_cat_join
        ON cats.cat_id = doc_cat_join.cat_id
        WHERE doc_cat_join.doc_id = '%s'
        ",

        mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $id) );

    $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q)
        or die ("Couldn't execute query: ".mysqli_error($dbc));


    // FETCH AND PRINT ALL THE RECORDS

    echo '<div class="view_body">';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
        echo '<a href="doc_view.php?doc_id='.$row["doc_id"].'"> '.$row["doc_name"]. '</a><br>';

    }
    echo '</div>';           
}
```

for some bizarre reason I get nothing, if I do a var_dump on $r I get the following:

```
string(168) " SELECT docs.doc_id,doc_name FROM docs INNER JOIN doc_cat_join ON cats.cat_id = doc_cat_join.cat_id WHERE doc_cat_join.doc_id = '24' "
```

So it gets the correct category ID I am in.

I am now getting th following output:

```
Couldn't execute query: Unknown column 'cats.cat_id' in 'on clause'
```

Comment: Where does `$r` come from? Are you calling `mysqli_query`? If so do you get any result from `mysqli_error`?

Comment: I have just realized that, I will update my code sorry.

Comment: YOu have an extra `}` at the end with no matching `{`

Comment: Your query has `cats.cat_id`, but it never joins with the `cats` table.

Comment: Sorry I am little confused? how should the query look?

Comment: What is the output you're trying to get? Why are you joining with the `doc_cat_join` table if you're not selecting anything from the `cats` table?

Comment: I am wanting to show any docs that are related to the cat - basically docs are like posts which are associated to cats (categories) and depending on which category you are looking at it will show the docs listed out in that category

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81618/discussion-between-phpcoder-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per your input and query design, your query should be as per below-

```
SELECT d.doc_id, d.doc_name 
FROM docs AS d 
INNER JOIN doc_cat_join AS dc ON dc.doc_id = d.doc_id WHERE dc.cat_id = '24';
```

Note: If it is not then show what output you require.

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = $_GET['cat_id']; 

$q = sprintf("
SELECT
*
FROM docs
INNER JOIN doc_cat_join
ON docs.doc_id = doc_cat_join.doc_id
INNER JOIN cat
ON doc_cat_join.cat_id = cat.cat_id
WHERE doc_cat_join.cat_id = '$id'
",

mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $id) );

print_r ($q);


// FETCH AND PRINT ALL THE RECORDS

echo '<div class="view_body">';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

echo '<a href="doc_view.php?doc_id='.$row["doc_id"].'"> '.$row["doc_name"].        '</a><br>';

}
echo '</div>';           
}
```

your query is wrong I think.

Comment: you join docs tbl and doc_cat_join.. so you should've used the doc_id instead of cat_id.

Comment: Ok so no more error but no output of data this time?

Comment: why are you using wildcard on the where clause?

Comment: Its a placeholder for the ID?

Comment: you are also passing the wrong id... why pass the `$_GET['cat_id']` when the one you need is doc_id? doesn't make sense

Comment: So what I am doing is, this query is called when you are on the category page so I am grabbing the id of the category from the url, I can use that as a reference point to show the docs that assigned to that cat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81620/discussion-between-phpcoder-and-user3113490).